# Getting "permission denied" error while running .jmx file from local Jenkins. Running perfectly fine from Terminal

Tags: jenkins, jmeter

Below is the console output from Jenkins:

```
+ sh jmeter.sh -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml -n -t /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Performance/JMeterTests/Request.jmx -l result.jtl
2018-03-26 03:12:31,390 main ERROR FileManager (jmeter.log) java.io.FileNotFoundException: jmeter.log (Permission denied) java.io.FileNotFoundException: jmeter.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.FileManager$FileManagerFactory.createManager(FileManager.java:290)
```

Comment: can you add write permission to jmeter.log? chmod 777 or 666?

Answer (score 2):

The error means that JMeter isn't able to create its log file in its working directory. You can configure JMeter to store its log file somewhere else, i.e. in a folder where user running Jenkins has read and write access to.

1. Locate the next line in *log4j2.xml* (the file lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   <File name="jmeter-log" fileName="${sys:jmeter.logfile:-jmeter.log}" append="false">
   ```
2. Amend `fileName` attribute value to point somewhere else, i.e. `/tmp/jmeter.log`

References:

- [Logging and error messages](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging)
- [How to Configure JMeter Logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging)

Comment: Hello, can you add simple example how change file destination into log4j2.xml file.